# Calling a function on Button click in elementor

Tags: php, html, wordpress, web, elementor

I am new to WordPress and elementor. I have created a form and I have to perform some functions on button click.
The functions are like redirecting to different or validating some information.
I inserted the HTML code element in the section and created the form. But I am not clear where to write the function and how to call it.

Below is the HTML code

```html
<input type="text" id="IMEI" name="IMEI" placeholder="Enter your IMEI here" class="textbox">
<input type="button" class="buttonchk" value="Check Phone">
<br>
<br>
```

Can someone please help

Comment: What would you use? Javascript function or PHP?

Comment: I am planning to use PHP.

Comment: Then you can add your function into the functions.php if you use a child theme. Or write a small Plugin.